# Undefined reference to '...' (libmodbus)

Tags: gcc, libmodbus

И вроде бы знаю где собака зарыта. Но никак не пойму что со мной не так.
Суть: пробная программка с использованием libmodbus (установлено из репов - libmodbus, libmodbus-dev):

```
#include <modbus.h>

int main (void)
{
  modbus_t *mb;
  uint16_t tab_reg[32];

  mb = modbus_new_tcp("127.0.0.1", 1502);
  modbus_connect(mb);

  /* Read 5 registers from the address 0 */
  modbus_read_registers(mb, 0, 5, tab_reg);

  modbus_close(mb);
  modbus_free(mb);

  return 0;
}
```

Компилирую:

```
gcc  -I/usr/include/modbus  -L/usr/lib -lmodbus main.c -o main
```

Вывод компилятора:

```
/tmp/cc6AsW7c.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `modbus_new_tcp'
main.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `modbus_connect'
main.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `modbus_read_registers'
main.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `modbus_close'
main.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `modbus_free'
collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
```

Примеры от разработчика libmodbus компилируются (у меня **не** компилируются), кстати, вот так:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus` main.c -o main
```

что, по-сути тоже самое, т.е. никаких финтов более не нужно.

Вот что не так? Библиотека на месте, путь указан. Не пойму.

Comment: возможно, библиотека у вас 32битная, а компилируете на 64битной. Проверьте ещё раз, какую именно версию dev библиотеки установили и какая разрядность системы.

Comment: Система x86_64 (Kubuntu 13.04). А как проверить библиотеку? Библиотека из репозитория, насколько я понимаю, 32х разрядной был бы суффикс ..32 или что-то типа i386?

Comment: Попробуйте `file`

    file /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 
    /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Возможно у Ваv нужен пакет совместимости с 32-бит. Если ничего не путаю

    sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Теперь можно запускать 32-бит приложения.

Comment: Вывод file:
/usr/lib/libmodbus.so.5.0.2: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x92b0111533c7e5a1b3f82157bf861e8a15dfde3f, stripped.
ia32-libs у меня установлен.

Comment: если у Вас среда 64битная (значит компилятор делает по умолчанию 64битный код) и либа такая же, то все должно быть нормально.

Comment: Так вот и я о том же! А оно вон оно как! Может библиотека кривая?

Comment: А `ldconfig` запускали, или просто закинули либу в /usr/lib?

Comment: @KoVadim -dev содержат хедеры, они не зависят от архитектуры :)

Comment: @eicto если библиотека только с хедерами, то да. В большинстве случаев это не так.

Только что проверил - установил только 32битную версию либы - не компилирует и ошибки такие же выдает. Указал явно 64битную версию dev либы и все скомпилировалось. Строка немного отличается

    gcc  -I/usr/include/modbus  -L/usr/lib64 -lmodbus main.c -o main

(у меня федора, если что)

Comment: @eicto от архитектуры зависит сама либа, которая обязана присутствовать когда установлены хедеры.
@avp - устанавливал aptitude, там, насколько я помню, вызов ldconfig автоматом. Но вручную ldconfig тоже запускал. Собственно первое, что на ум пришло. Не помогло ((

Comment: @decodder, а проверьте, все-таки в этой либе точно есть эти функции?

Поскольку она стрипнутая, то вместо `nm` читайте `readelf -s`.

Answer (score 2):

В продолжение вышеизложенного.

Собрал библиотеку из исходников. Установил. Проблема та же.

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) - применительно к вновь установленной библиотеке (не стрип):

```
nm /usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so.5.0.4 | grep modbus_new_tcp
00000000000063e0 T modbus_new_tcp
00000000000064d0 T modbus_new_tcp_pi
```

Компилятор:

```
/tmp/ccxxrcfD.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `modbus_new_tcp'
...
```

**UPD:** Решение нашлось! Легким движением руки меняем аргументы при компиляции местами:

```
gcc  main.c -o main -I/usr/include/modbus  -L/usr/lib -lmodbus
```

И вуаля! И не задумывался, если честно, что порядок тут важен.
Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А текст

    `pkg-config --cflags --libs libmodbus`

в тестах от разработчиков, что выводит?

Кстати, если сами собирали, то с `.a` собирается? Или они делают только .so, можно еще попробовать для своей .so

    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/my_lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @avp - -I/usr/local/include/modbus  -L/usr/local/lib -lmodbus
Про "a" немного не понял. Уже понял. Да. Только .so. Попробую.

Comment: Часто собирают 2 версии библиотек, одна libmylib.so для динамической линковки, а другая libmylib.a для статической (обычный ar-овский архив .o).

--

Что-то странное, конечно у Вас. Надо бы на атрибуты при функциях в исходнике и Makefile, которым либу делали глянуть.

--

А вообще я настороженно отношусь к программкам, которым всякие `pkg-config` нужны...

Comment: > А вообще я настороженно отношусь к программкам, которым всякие pkg-config нужны...

pkg-config - это хорошая штука. Она помогает сильно упростить makefile.

Comment: Все хорошо, когда работает. А хорошо работают простые вещи.

Comment: Надо же, век живи, век учись... 

Даже не поверил, попробовал:

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/solib$ make
    gcc -o p1 p1.c -labc -L. 
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/solib$ gcc -labc -L. p1.c
    /tmp/ccXljivV.o: In function `main':
    p1.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `f1'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/solib$ gcc  -L. p1.c -labc
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/solib$ echo $?
    0
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/dispro/solib$ 


и в самом деле. Только расположение -I, -L, конечно, не влияет.